# Ionic 2 ion-item-sliding error when updating object

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

i'm trying to use the ion-item-sliding of a ion-list with this code :

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let device of devices" class="item-sliding-joueur-balise">
    <ion-item class="item-joueur-balise" *ngIf="device.player">
    <ion-avatar item-left><img left="" src={{device.player.urlImage}}/></ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>{{device.player.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label right>Balise {{device.id}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
<ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button class="button-edit-balise" (click)="handleEditBalise(device)">
    <ion-icon class="icon-action" name="md-create"></ion-icon>
    <label class="label-action">Balise</label>
    </button>
    <button ion-button color="danger" style="width:80px" (click)="deleteDevice(device)">
    <ion-icon class="icon-action-size" name="trash"></ion-icon>
    <label class="label-action">Supprimer</label>
    </button>
</ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

But when I click on the delete button that executes the deleteDevice(device)
, I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setElementStyle' of undefined
    at ItemSliding._setOpenAmount (item-sliding.js:396)
    at ItemSliding.close (item-sliding.js:477)
    at ItemSlidingGesture.closeOpened (item-sliding-gesture.js:104)
    at ItemSlidingGesture.canStart (item-sliding-gesture.js:50)
    at ItemSlidingGesture.PanGesture.pointerDown (drag-gesture.js:79)
    at PointerEvents.handleTouchStart (pointer-events.js:43)
```

The deleteDevice function is :

```
 deleteDevice(device: Device): void {
    device.player= null;
    }
```

I seems that when I try to modify the device element of the list i get this error but i don't know how to solve it and why is it happening.

Any ideas please ? (i don't want to use the splice function on devices but juste set the player of the device to null)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem came from the *ngIf="device.player"
I replaced it with [hidden]="!device.player" and it worked like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment for now so...

My idea to help you is, if you pass the key of the array `devices` and delete the actual `device`, so the function looks something like this:

```
deleteDevice(key) {
   this.devices.splice(key, 1);
}
```

Comment: yeah i know that splice works, but that's not really what i want. I just want to make the player null for the device so that it's not linked to it anymore.

Comment: @batmaniac well, maybe for some other users should works like they want, It's good to have other options. I hope I have helped